# Should my aftermarket frame have a serial number on it?

Tags: frames, bmx

I was riding a mostly custom WTP Crysis frame which had a serial in case the bike was lost or stolen. I snapped the drop out arms on Sunday and ended up buying a new FBM Hard Way frame. I checked all over and haven't seen the serial numbers. Part of me thinks there should definitely be one, but I'm not sure where to look.

Does FBM allow me to register it online? I don't want to be at the point where the only evidence of it being my bike is "I have this pic of it in my apartment" and a bike shop receipt. But my bike shop receipt only says "BMX 20.75" frame" and doesn't say make, model or even color.

Comment: My tandem has no serial number, but it was hand made by a man with a gas welder while wearing a leather workshop apron.   Did you buy your new frame from a reputable dealer or a disreputable one ?

Comment: I bought it from a local bikeshop in Providence which seems to be very reputable within the BMX scene.

Comment: if you bought it new - consider consulting the bike shop directly.  Could be the serial number is elsewhere ?

Comment: Did some digging and it looks like FBM chooses to put the serial plate on the inside of the BB, instead of underneath it. So I will have to dismantle my bike to chick it out.

Comment: That's a strange place to put a serial number, but its also kinda smart.  hard to access means its hard to change.  Also I bet it was written on the original warranty card or other documentation.  Good spotting - once you confirm the location of the serial number, add an answer and accept it.  This is totally acceptable by SE's rules - its all about The Answer.

Comment: I was told by FBM Warranty dept where to look and can confirm that on the 2015-2016 FBM Hardway frame, it is indeed in the bottom bracket. That being said, i didn't receive a warranty call, but they apparently know the bikeshop really well and told me if I have a problem to bring it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking to FBM's warranty department, they have confirmed that on the Hard Way, and a couple other frames, the serial number is located on a plate within the Bottom Bracket housing. I took my bike apart and found it right where they stated.

Mine was on the left hand (if you're standing over the frame) side, but this could vary.

Comment: Good work - now click the little tickbox / check mark to make this the Accepted answer, because its what worked for you.

Comment: @Criggie I know, I had a 3hour waiting period and forgot haha

Answer (score 3):

I would be surprised if any quality frame does not have a serial number. Many manufacturers warn against frames with no number, or numbers scratched off, so your concern is somewhat valid and you should follow up on it. Also reading http://fbmbmx.com/products/frames/fbm_warranty.php suggests the frame should have come with a warranty card.

Photograph the frame with the receipt and send it to them, specifically expressing your concerns. They will confirm fairly quickly if its genuine.

Comment: There are a lot of fake frames coming out of China these days, especially imitations of quality brand name frames (which in some case fail catastrophically when the original would be fine). I'd be inclined to think fake if the frame had no serial number.

Comment: I did some more digging, and found out that FBM usually puts them inside the bottom bracket, which is a bummer since I'll have to take apart the bike just to get the serial # (if that is even where it is). I will try sending a few pics to FBM to try and confirm it.