# do all diamondback bmx bikes have a serial number on them?

Tags: bmx

I have a diamondback bmx and am sure it is authentic however it doesn't have a serial number anywhere on the frame and certainly not where you would expect it to be ( between where the arm and the crankshaft attach.

Comment: See also https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/should-my-aftermarket-frame-have-a-serial-number-on-it   The S/N might be inside the head tube, or inside the bottom bracket housing too.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all bikes have a serial number on them.

Exceptions might be

- A home made bike
- A small bespoke framebuilder (rare)
- A repaired bike where the part that had the number was replaced
- A stolen bike, where someone has ground-off the number to inhibit identification.

A serial number is not overly useful, since you know the brand, hopefully the manufacturer has a system, or has records still, and lets you look them up.  More on serials: [What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number)